# NSCFString appendString leak while parsing xml

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks, nsxmlparser, nsmutablestring

I am having trouble removing leaks from an iPhone app that i'm working on.  I am parsing an xml feed to get data.
Here is the code I am using to parse

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setMemoryCapacity:0];
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setDiskCapacity:0]; 
    NSData *xml = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"url link"]];
    self.parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:xml];   


[self.parser setDelegate:self];
[self.parser parse];
[self.parser release];
self.parser=nil;
```

And the parsing code

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict { if(![elementName compare:@"item"])
{tempElement = [[XMLElement alloc] init];
}
else if(![elementName compare:@"title"])
{
    self.currentAttribute = [NSMutableString string];
}

else if(![elementName compare:@"link"])
{
    self.currentAttribute = [NSMutableString string];
}
else if(![elementName compare:@"comments"])
{
    self.currentAttribute = [NSMutableString string];
}
else if(![elementName compare:@"pubDate"])
{
    self.currentAttribute = [NSMutableString string];
}
else if(![elementName compare:@"category"])
{
    self.currentAttribute = [NSMutableString string];
}

else if(![elementName compare:@"description"])
{
    self.currentAttribute = [NSMutableString string];
}}
```

I am getting a leak on each

```
self.currentAttribute = [NSMutableString string];
```

and on

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{NSString *strAppend = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
if ([strAppend length] > 0) {
    [self.currentAttribute appendString:string];
}
```

}

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot but, i was not calling the dealloc function inside my object class. Adding this function and releasing all strings using [self.mystring release] solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

If your properties are being retained, like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSXMLParser * parser;
```

...then they're getting retained twice. So one release won't do it.
You could set them up like this:

```
NSXMLParser *tempParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:xml];
self.parser = tempParser;
[tempParser release];
```

Then do whatever you need with self.parser.
Then in your dealloc method, you release it. Since this way it's left with a retain count of 1 (the original alloc retain having been released with tempParser), one release should do it:

```
- (void) dealloc {
[parser release];
[super dealloc];
}
```

Also, I'm puzzled why you would go to the trouble of writing if-else statements if each possibility has the same result.